# Definition of mutation types in namespaced module

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a namespaced Vuex module. If I commit a mutation as follows:

```
this.$store.commit('myModuleName/' + mutationTypes.SOME_MUTATION_TYPE)
```

It is working well. However, I have multiple `mutation-types.js` files which I import 
to get mutation names of well defined modules and -in order to avoid mentioning the module name all the time- I came up with following solution in `mutation-types.js`:

```
let prefix = 'myModuleName'
export const SOME_MUTATION_TYPE= prefix + 'SOME_MUTATION_TYPE'
//or as follows, the same result:
export const SOME_MUTATION_TYPE= 'myModuleName/SOME_MUTATION_TYPE'
```

And if I then commit that same mutation as follows:

```
this.$store.commit(mutationTypes.SOME_MUTATION_TYPE)
```

Mutation is not committed and got the following error:

```
[vuex] unknown mutation type: myModuleName/SOME_MUTATION_TYPE
```

What I commit is actually the same in both scenarios, however, in the latter case I get that error.

Why is that? Is that something we can solve? Or what is better/commonly-used way to realize it?

Comment: What does `mutationTypes.SOME_MUTATION_TYPE` return in your first example? Does it return the string `SOME_MUTATION_TYPE`? The variable you pass into `this.$store.commit(...)` is simply a string, so simply log the variable somewhere and check if they are different in your first and second scenarios.

Comment: did it and they are both string. Even tried `this.$store.commit(''+mutationTypes.SOME_MUTATION_TYPE)`

Comment: They are both strings, but do they have the same value? Perhaps it's easier for you to create an MCVE, since it's really difficult for us to see what you've done wrong.